# Number input replacing decimal comma with dot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, input, number-formatting

After posting the form with an input of type 'number' and value "1,5", the browser (Chrome 43.0.2357.130, FF 38.0.5) is sending the number with a dot as decimal separator, but the input has attribute lang="cs" (in Czech Republic we use decimal comma), so for ASP.NET MVC it's the incorrect format.

How can I set the browser (form/input) to send what user really filled ("1,5" in my case)?

The form data sent from the browser:

```
__RequestVerificationToken:KJG1yJxm-1EcUHPwgvr0gPpkyoEHHHcTfSu6hHvaKDA_XKHTzWfPfUJtAr11gNiR_euG_jWYmXlrMO7dyhSf7g4K74eOVTtEzLQ1OdrTLZ_cbIyyYj5vrgxlk81JzuhM0
PaymentMethodId:8
PaymentMethod:Direct payment
Provider:Direct payment
MinAmount:1,00000000
MaxAmount:5000,00000000
Amount:1.5
```

Comment: Can we see your code as well?

Comment: you mean html, razer view or post action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oukey, it looks like I found workaround, but look at it as example how you can handle similar issue...

```
public class ApolloModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        decimal i;
        var value = request.Form[propertyDescriptor.Name];
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) && decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i))
        {
            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, i);
            return;
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers that support `<input type="number">` will always send a `.` as a decimal separator. You cannot change this, as this is per the HTML5 specifications for `<input type="number">`. The `lang` attribute is not relevant for the data that is sent to the server: the browser must always use a `.`. The `lang` attribute may be used for display purposes, however.

However, browsers that do not support `<input type="number">` will send the number as you have typed it (with e.g., `,`).

IMHO, this is highly problematic (and very anglocentric), since the server does not know whether the browser supports `<input type="number">` or not, making parsing highly error prone (is "1.000" one thousand or one?).

The only way you can control what is sent, is by using `<input type="text">`. And if you want spinner functionality, you'll need to use custom JavaScript libraries, like jQuery UI.

This is also why ASP.NET MVC Editor(For) will use `<input type="text">` by default for types like **decimal**, rather than `<input type="number">`.

See also http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#input-author-notes.

Note that Internet Explorer will send number inputs as the user typed them, ignoring the specification.

Comment: I was looking to specification, but I found nothing about decimal separator, so can you send me link? Well, that's a reason to use lang attribut, with this attribute you can say what culture you're currently working. And reason why I want to use number is number keyboard on mobile devices - that field is for money amount, so this is pretty example to use number, I think.

Comment: @SebastianBusek, I've added a link to the HTML5 spec that comments on this.